# Convert mathematical signal to sound

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu, math, signal-processing

I use `Ubuntu 22.04`. Is there an application for converting mathematical periodical `sin/cos` formula (functions) to sound? For example is there a way for playing these signals:

- `cos(2π · 440 t)`
- `cos t + cos 2^(1/2) t`

Features:

- I only look for free applications.
- I prefer a desktop application; but a simple web application is also acceptable.

Note:

- I have installed `FFmpeg` and `Octave` on my machine.
- A web page which describes the way of using those for my purpose is acceptable.

Comment: In MATLAB, there is [`sound`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html). Is there an equivalent function in Octave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Octave 5, you can use `audiowrite` (older versions used `wavwrite`) as listed here:

https://docs.octave.org/v5.2.0/Audio-File-Utilities.html#index-audiowrite

The first formula `cos(2π · 440 t)` can be exported into a WAV like this:

```
octave:1> fs = 44100;                           % set the sample rate in Hz
octave:2> data = cos(2*pi * 440 * (1:fs) / fs); % create the data
octave:3> audiowrite('cosinus.wav', data, fs);  % save data as wav file
```

Maybe something similar is possible for your second formula.